# viewport movement with head tracking in Oculus

Tags: tracking, oculus

I integrate oculus sdk 1.3.0 into our game engine, have some problem; as can see from the picture attached, the viewport is also moved as I moved my head. So can someone know what's wrong about this situation?[image]

Comment: You should show how you are setting up the texture sets, the eye buffer sizes, how you call submit frame, etc.

Comment: Well if you still have this problem, paste part of your code to see why the viewport is moving